# How do I get the width and height of a cell in pixels? excel, openpyxl, python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How do I get the width and height of a cell in pixels? excel, openpyxl, python
I need to fit the picture by cell size

Answer (score 0):

for VBA you just need call cells(row,col).width